# Chrome webstore stopped updating my extension's reviews

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a quite popular Chrome extension (over 100K users).
I watch its stats and reviews from time to time, now I see that user reviews haven't updated for a week now, anybody knows why this happens?
Did happen to me before, I think, but usually only for a day or two.
(extension name is "wikiwand - wikipedia modernized"
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered that people simply aren't leaving reviews? I have extensions that have ~15K users, and there may be no reviews for months. _Anyway_, this is probably an inappropriate place to ask.

Comment: Obviously I wouldn't ask this question unless I was sure that there should have been reviews. I typically get 2-3 reviews each day, so it seems unreasonable to me that I have seen nothing for a week.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Xan was right after all.
How embarrassing for me. Due to an unrelated change, I wasn't prompting users to rate the extension these last few days.